# Cant scroll through video when using temporary link

Tags: php, html, video

I'am using a technique to prevent my users from downloading videos with temporary links but the problem is when i provide a link in the source tag the video loads but cant be scrolled (example: from 0:00 to 1:25) thats my code for the index page where video element is created and a link is attached

```
<?php 
include_once('dbconfig.php');

function mysql_date($time, $opt = ''){
    switch($opt){
        case 0:
            //Return datetime
            return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
            break;
        default:
            //Return default date
            return date('Y-m-d', $time);
    }
}

function generate_link($filename){
    $id = uniqid();

    $timestamp = mysql_date(time(), 0);

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `temporary_links`(`filename`, `token`, 
`timestamp`) VALUES ("' . $filename. '", "' . $id. '", "' . $timestamp . 
'")');

    return 'stream.php?i=' . $id;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="600" height="300" controls>
        <source src="<?php echo generate_link('music.mp4'); ?>" 
type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <video width="600" height="300" controls preload="none">
        <source src="music.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

And then this is the file where the video file is read

```
<?php 
include_once('dbconfig.php');

if(isset($_GET['i']) && !empty($_GET['i'])){
    $id = $_GET['i'];

    $filename_query = mysql_query('SELECT `filename`, `token` FROM `temporary_links` WHERE `token`="' . $id . '"');

    if(mysql_num_rows($filename_query) > 0){
        $filename = mysql_fetch_assoc($filename_query);

        $filename = $filename['filename'];

        destroy_link($id);

        if(file_exists($filename)){
            ob_get_clean();

            header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

            readfile($filename);

            ob_flush();
            flush();
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }
}

function destroy_link($id){
    return mysql_query('DELETE FROM `temporary_links` WHERE `token`="' . $id . '"');
}
?>
```

Once again the video loads perfectly but cant be skipped for example from (0:00 to 1:20). Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: do you get any error in the browser console (especially under networking)? My guess is that the link is being destroyed before the browser has read the entire video.

Comment: No there is no error